# Image package on octave fails due to unsatisified dependencies

Tags: octave

I have Octave 3.8.4 installed which is the last version of Octave in repositories when i try to install image package on it

using pkg install -forge image

i got the following error message

error: the following dependencies were unsatisfied:
   image needs octave >= 4.0.0

Comment: Which distribution? You should use your package system to install the forge packages (apt-get for example). Or build Octave from tarball and use pkg -forge install

Comment: my System is Linux Mint 17 , i tried to compile Octave myself from their repositories , i installed the image package using apt-get but it still cannot be used

Comment: "it cannot be used" is not a sufficient description. Describe your problem better on the Octave help mailinglist (this is not a stackoverflow programming help question)

Comment: you need to upgrade your Octave installation. Octave 4.0.0 was released a few days ago and many Octave packages are already dependent on it.